# How does Santa deal with unbelieving parents?

Tags: santa-claus

This question is specifically about presents left by Santa and not about his existence.

Presume:

- Santa exists.
- He delivers presents to all good children.
- He does not have to deliver presents by traditional methods.
- Time is not an issue, Santa perfected time stretching decades ago.

So why:

- do a large portion of the children around the world get no Christmas presents?
- Parents not get confused by the extra present under the tree?
- Some kids do not get two presents from 'Santa' (one actually being from their disbelieving parents)?

Santa must deliver the presents, he cannot cede this duty to disbelieving parents. He is indiscriminate; it is not the child's fault if they do not believe in him, and the child still gets a present (presume childhood stops at 16).

Is there some evil force at work which steals the presents? If so, what does it do with them? Why hasn't Santa trained a force of fighter elves to stop it?

More Detail:

Children who do not get presents are not necessarily naughty. Santa's nice list will have everyone with a 'good heart' on it. Basically small bad acts (not handing in your homework on time every time, pulling your sibling's hair when they make faces at you, etc.) do not put you on the naughty list. So answers should not include most kids being on the naughty list.

I don't mind magic, but I would prefer a solution other than mind meddling/altering, this is a dangerous and presumably intensive process.

I would prefer a more physical reason, such as a villain opposed to Santa who steals presents. Maybe the villain gets stronger with an increasing amount of something? But why would the villain steal the toys?

Comment: I think this is too broad. There could be any number of made up situations which would be equally as valid.

Comment: The word of the day is *"Magic"*

Answer (score 2):

> Why do a large portion of the children around the world get no Christmas presents?

But they do. But their parents don't want them to have the presents, because they want to make their children believe, there is no Santa.

> Parents not get confused by the extra present under the tree?

They do. For a second, but then tell them selfes, hey an extra present for our little ones and we didn't pay for it? Tops!

> Why some kids do not get two presents from 'Santa'?

That has definitely nothing to do with Santa, but as I stated two week ago on the question "How many elves are working at the north pole" that the shipping department is running SAP and it wasn't perfectly installed. So Santa doesn't always carry enough presents around and the kids who only get one present... well tough luck, end of the line, try again next year.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason why so many children do not get Christams gifts is not their parents lack of belief in Santa Claus. It's lack of money.

Comment: @LuísHenrique I totally agree, but the question wasn't meant to be serious.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because they haven't been good and they are now on the naughty list or their parents forgot to mail Santa their letter.
2. Santa implants false memories in the minds of parents can make them think that they brought the kids a gift.
3. Kids get two (or more) gifts from their parents all the time the awesome one is from Santa ( the parents only think that they got it because Santa's elves and planted them false memories in their minds), the lame ones are the only ones the parents actually got them.